# Filepicker.io issue with drag and drop on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, filepicker.io

I have been using filepicker for my latest project and quite happy with its robustness and simplicity.

However, our QA uncovered a bug with the filepicker widget on chrome. Trying to do drag and drop of file on chrome, causes the page to refresh and display the image on the browser. I noticed on the console that we get an error

```
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg"
```

This issue is also seen on the filepicker widget in the documentation mentioned here https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick

I did some research about this problem on SO and other places on the web, and the answers seem to point to a server side issue. However, at this point my script is not communicating with the server side at all, so I am a bit confused.

This functionality is working smoothly on FF.

I would appreciate any help our pointers on how to resolve this.

Best regards,

Titash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was introduced via a behavior change on how Chrome deals with dragOver events. A patch has been created for Filepicker.io, everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I truly appreciate your support and prompt response. Will wait for this to golive.

Comment: Yes, I am seeing this behavior as fixed. Thanks